# What are the benefits of a Make Table vs a Select query in Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I know you can run SELECT queries on top of SELECT queries in Access, but the application also provides the Make Table query type.

I'm wondering what the benefits/reasons for using Make Table might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would usually use `Make Table` for performance reasons. If you have a fairly complex query that returns a subset of your table's data, and that you may need to retrieve multiple times, it can be expensive to re-run the query multiple times.

Using `Make Table` allows you to incur the cost of running the expensive query *once*, and make a copy of the query results into a table.  Querying this *copy* would then be a lot less expensive than running your original expensive query.

This is usually a good option when you don't expect your original data to change frequently, or if you don't care that you are working of a copy of the data that may not be 100% up-to-date with the original data.

Notice what the following article on [Create a make table query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-make-table-query-96424f9e-82fd-411e-aca4-e21ad0a94f1b) has to say:

> Typically, you create make table queries when you need to copy or archive data. For example, suppose you have a table (or tables) of past sales data, and you use that data in reports. The sales figures cannot change because the transactions are at least one day old, and constantly running a query to retrieve the data can take time — especially if you run a complex query against a large data store. Loading the data into a separate table and using that table as a data source can reduce workload and provide a convenient data archive. As you proceed, remember that the data in your new table is strictly a snapshot; it has no relationship or connection to its source table or tables.

Comment: Just as a note, make table should not be used casually because of MS Access tendency to bloat.

Answer (score 1):

The main defense here is that a make table query creates a table. And when you done with the table then effort and time to delete that table and recover the VERY LARGE increase in the database file will have to occur. For general reports and a query of data make much more send. A comparison would be to build a NEW garage every time you want to park your car.

The database engine and query system can fetch and pull rows at a very high rate and those results are then able to be rendered into a report or form, and this occurs without having to create a temp table. It makes little sense to go through all of the trouble of having the system create a WHOLE NEW table for such results of data when they can with ease be sent to a report.

In other words creating a whole table just to display or use some data that the database engine already fetched and returned makes little sense. A table is a set of rows that holds data that can be updated and the results are permanent. A query is a “on the fly” results or sub set of data that only exists in memory and is discarded after you use the results.

So for general reporting and display of data, it makes no sense to create a temp table. MUCH WORSE of an issue is that if you have two users wanting to run a report, if they both need different results and you send the results to the SAME temp table, then you have a big mess and collision between the two users. So use of a temp table in Access for the most part makes little sense, and this is EVEN MORE so when working in a multi-user environment. And as noted, once the table is created, then after you are done you need to delete and remove the table. And with many users in a multi-user database this becomes even more of a problem and issue.

However in a multi-user environment as pointed out that if the resulting data needs additional processing, then sending the results to a temp table can be of use. This approach however suggests that EACH USER has their own front end and own copy of the application side. And better is that the temp table is created outside of the front end application that resides on each computer. Since the application part (front end) is placed on each computer, then creating of a temp table does not occur in the production database (back end) and as a result you can have multiple users function correctly without each individual user creating  a temp table in the production back end database. So if one is to adopt a make table query, it likely should occur on each local workstation and not in the back end database when you have a multiple user database application.

Thus for the most part a make table and that of reports and query of data are VERY different goals and tasks. You don't want nor as a general rule create a whole brand new table for a simple query. In a multi user database system the users might run 100's of reports in a given day and FEW if any systems will send such data to a temp table in place of sending the query results directly to the report.

Answer (score 0):

It creates a table - which is useful if you have a need for that table which you may have for temporary use where you have to modify the data for calculations or further processing while not disturbing the original data.

Comment: But couldn't you use a select query add create a new field which is defined by a calculation (Leaving all of the original fields untouched). Maybe I'm misunderstanding.